# How to handle HTTP ERROR 500 on WordPress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, cpanel, wp-admin

I recently added a plugin to my WordPress site to reset the site. The plugin is 'WP Reset'. The plugin was working just fine, until I used it to reset the site. Right after clicking reset this appeared:

[image: [This page isn’t working error (error code 500)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaiR1.png)]

I've done some research and watched some videos, and I've learnt this happens because of the plugin. I'm suppose to deactivate it. But I can't even log into the dashboard, and now that's a whole new problem. I've also tried going to the dashboard through cPanel, but when I try login in using mydomainname:2083 cPanel doesnt work either

Answer (score 0):

Errors 5xx is usually DB errors. Could you go to `wp-config.php` file and open the DEBUG mode (about line 82), in order to see more details about this error. Make this code of line:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', false );
```

to

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
```

If your have **FTP access** you could go to `/wp-content/themes/plugins/`
and **rename** the folder of the plugin "wp-reset" to something else for example "__wp-reset". This way the plugin will be inactive and you could access the admin panel of WordPress, if the problem comes from WP reset plugin.

However, the cpanel access, does not have any relation to the WP issue. Are you sure the port you are using from your hosting provider, is correct?

Give us more details so we could help you

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. I tried all of these, including renaming the file, and the problem still persisted. Eventually I was told the problem was from the fact that the php version on the server was old, and that was what was conflicting with the new plugin I had installed

Answer (score 0):

To know which plugin cause the error 500 you should activate the debug mode (read more [here](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/debugging-in-wordpress/)) and redirect it to a file:

```
    // Enable WP_DEBUG mode
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );

// Enable Debug logging to the /wp-content/debug.log file
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );

// Disable display of errors and warnings
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
@ini_set( 'display_errors', 0 );

// Use dev versions of core JS and CSS files (only needed if you are modifying these core files)
define( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG', true );
```